# Local storage set item not setting the value with key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My argument works fine in consoling or setting the local storage value in the function after click event. But I want to set it by passing it on window obj globally in Vue.

```
AppStorage.storeLocation(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

This argument works fine. And the app storage is defined globally in app.js file.

```
import AppStorage from './helpers/AppStorage';
window.AppStorage = AppStorage;
```

This is my appstorage file:

```
class AppStorage{
    storeLat(lat){
        localStorage.setItem('lattitude',lat);
    }
    storeLong(long){
        localStorage.setItem('longitude',long);
    }
    storeLocation(lat,long){
        this.storeLat(lat);
        this.storeLong(long);
    }
   
}
export default AppStorage = new AppStorage();
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: It's unknown why it's not working. What does this mean at all? Is value null or it's not changed? The obvious reason would be that values are wrong, but currently you're the only person who can check this. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an rewrite the `AppStorage.js` file like

```
class AppStorage {
  setItem(name, content) {
    if (!name) return;
    if (typeof content !== "string") {
      content = JSON.stringify(content);
    }
    return localStorage.setItem(name, content);
  }
  getItem(name) {
    if (!name) return;
    const localValues = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (typeof localValues === "string") {
      return JSON.parse(localValues);
    } else {
      return localValues;
    }
  }
}
export default AppStorage = new AppStorage();
```

Save to LocalStorage:

```
AppStorage.setItem("location",JSON.stringify({ latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude }));
```

Retrive from LocalStorage:

```
AppStorage.getItem("location");
```

You can `store` and `retrive` `localStorage` values to `App.vue` component like,

Complete source code of `app.vue` component

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>LocalStorage Latitude: {{ location.latitude }}</p>
    <p>LocalStorage Latitude: {{ location.longitude }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import AppStorage from "./helpers/AppStorage";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      location: {},
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.loadGeolocation();
  },
  methods: {
    async loadGeolocation() {
      await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        if (position) {
          console.log("position", position.coords);
          AppStorage.setItem(
            "location",
            JSON.stringify({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            })
          );
          this.loadFromLocalStorage();
        }
      });
    },
    loadFromLocalStorage() {
      this.location = AppStorage.getItem("location");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

[DEMO Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-hertz-x3c7g)